# Handling the unexpected popup ad's in website

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am currently working on Automation project for E-commerce site. In some pages unexpected popup's(ex:ad's) are displaying. Because of that my script was failing by throwing exceptions like `ElementNotFoundException` and currently `Element is not Interactable` etc.. . Here these ad's are not specific to particular page. It may come at any page.

Please let me know, Is there any way to handle these type of scenario?

Comment: is that ad comes in iframe? can you please share that web page URL?

Comment: No, it includes in Website

Comment: can you please share website URL?

Comment: it is local url

Comment: you should share that page screenshot and html code of that page ad. part.

Comment: Hello Helping hands , I can able to handle that popup if it comes in a particular page.But my scenario is that popup is use to come unexpectedly(may in the opening page or later after moved to 3 to 4 screens). May be I confused  you with less description.I hope your are clear now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31171/discussion-between-qamember-and-helping-hands).

Comment: Don't understand why the question was down voted. In my sense, it is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Can any one help in handling random adds popup , we dont know when it appears , due to which i m getting problem in handling those popups , u can see such popups on 1mg.com

Answer (score 3):

To provide an exact solution to the question screenshot of the popup is necessary (I am just gonna state out all possible scenarios).
A popup can be an alert or an ad in a iframe or an ad in a new window and all these are treated in different ways.

1. Assuming its an Alert, log_file has already provided you the solution, i.e. to use `alertIsPresent`(), and accept or dimiss it as per your requirements.
2. Assuming the ad is in `iframe`, follow the below approach:

   ```
   driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(By.id(locatorToIdentifyFrame)));       
   driver.findElement(By.id(locatorToCloseAd)).click(); //Close Ad
   driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // Return to main window
   ```
3. Assuming the ad in the `window`, follow the below approach:

   ```
   String mainWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Get your main window
   String subWinHandle = null;

   Set<String> allHandle = driver.getWindowHandles(); // Fetch all handles
   Iterator<String> iterator = allHandle.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()){
       subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
   }
   driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup 

   //Write code to close Ad or skip                                            

   driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
   ```

So, you need to use `ExpectedConditions` in all the three scenarios and based on your need, please put them into a function and call them in your `@BeforeTest` or `@Test` (not all but atleast in those scenarios where you suspect an unexepected ad might appear).

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know, Is there any way to handle these type of scenario's

Depending on your toolset, you could check for the pop-up and close it if it exists (with each page load). If it's a modal (and not an alert or new window) that will be a bit easier, especially in Selenium (or Selenium IDE with the SideFlow plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Try to control the JS Alert in the `@BeforeTest`, if you are using `TestNG` (or in the `def setUp( )` if using `PyUnit`).

The Steps would be something like this :

1. Initialize your test (getting the URL and maximize the window etc.)
2. Wait for 30 seconds to check for `alertIsPresent( )` using `ExpectedConditions`.
3. If alert is present, then accept the alert and continue.
4. If wait fails, then do something (print something like alert not present) and carry on with your work.